# Lead free compliant question

Tags: lead-free, rohs

Do hand tools such as cutters and pliers have to be replaced to switch over to lead free soldering station to be compliant?

Comment: I don't think so, unless they are made (partially) of lead and you leave them in the final product, neither of which seems very likely.

Comment: I would switch out anything that has gotten leaded solder spilled or splattered on it, but otherwise I'd leave them.

Comment: Except rasps. I probably wouldn't chance those.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about RoHS compliance, then they don't need to be lead free.  RoHS only covers the material in the product.  Also keep in mind that RoHS covers more than just lead.  There are 6 substances that it restricts.